# Quantum mechanics of wave packets of light

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, optics, particle-physics, quantum-optics

Two photons moving in a given direction at speed, $c$, the first wave packet of light starting at $|\Psi_{1}(x,0)\rangle$ and after time, $t$, it is in the state $|\Psi_{1}(x,t)\rangle$. There is also another photon moving in the opposite direction in initial state $|\Psi_{2}(x,0)\rangle$ and after the same time, $t$ its state is $|\Psi_{2}(x,t)\rangle$. You can say that the inital states of both photons are orthogonal: $\langle \Psi_{1}(x,0)|\Psi_{2}(x,0)\rangle=0$ but after time, $t$, they are not orthogonal: $\langle \Psi_{1}(x,t)|\Psi_{2}(x,t)\rangle \neq 0$. By introducing two distinct directions of propagation, $s=\pm 1$ you can fix this and the final states are now orthogonal $\langle \Psi_{1}(x,t)|\Psi_{2}(x,t)\rangle=0$, showing that there is a Hamiltonian. How would you figure out this Hamiltonian ?

Comment: May I ask what is meant by "showing that there is a Hamiltonian"?

Comment: Please explain: What is $s$?

Comment: In particle physics a photon is a point elementary particle. Any wave packet model has to be in the probability modeling. In you model why they are not orthogonal after time t? There must be interactions to become so.

Comment: @garyp the two distinct directions of motion